# Symfony 4 on XAMPP - make:migration does't work, could not find driver

Tags: mysql, doctrine, migration, symfony4

ALERT: WAIT BEFORE MARKING THIS AS A DUPLICATE, THERE ARE A LOT OF SIMILIAR QUESTIONS HERE, BUT NOTHING THAT WORKED FOR ME.

I'm starting to learn the php framework Symfony and I have some problems with Entities and migration. When i try to run the command `bin/console make:migration` on my git Bush, it gives me these errors:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 106:
  An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

In PDOConnection.php line 31:
  could not find driver

In PDOConnection.php line 27:
  could not find driver
```

I am working with Symfony 4. My PC is a Windows 10 and the code is running in an Apache server made with XAMPP. The DB is local (always made with XAMPP) and it is MySQL (server MariaDB 10.4.6).The PHP version is 7.3.9.

This is my .env Symfony file:

```
    ###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
    APP_ENV=dev
    APP_SECRET=b9c673023606f26343aee9c3d24a8aba
    #TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
    #TRUSTED_HOSTS='^localhost|example\.com$'
    ###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

    ###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
    # Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
    # For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
    # Configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
    DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@localhost:3306/symfony
    ###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

    ###> symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
    # For Gmail as a transport, use: "gmail://username:password@localhost"
    # For a generic SMTP server, use: "smtp://localhost:25?encryption=&auth_mode="
    # Delivery is disabled by default via "null://localhost"
    MAILER_URL=null://localhost

###< symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
```

this is my doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

In this file I tried to change the driver with `php_pdo_mysql` (in `c:\xampp\php\ext` I have a file with this name), the charset, the db version (in `mariadb-10.4.6`) but nothing changed.

In my php.ini (the once at `c:\xampp\php` ) I already removed the semicolon at `extension=pdo_mysql` but nothing changed.

I've also tried to uninstall and re-install doctrine, to create a new project, to search online for some sort of "mysql drivers" (maybe I searched the wrong things) and also to uninstall and re-install the entire xampp.

Nothing worked.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If you run `php -m` in output can you see pdo_mysql?

Comment: try removing semicolon to extension=php_pdo_mysql in php.ini

Comment: @AndreaManzi no, all I see is: `bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib`

Comment: please post output of `php -i | findstr /c:"Loaded Configuration File"`

Comment: on windows cmd it returns to me `Loaded Configuration File => C:\Program Files (x86)\php\php.ini`

Comment: on git bush `stdout is not a tty`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199852/discussion-between-andrea-manzi-and-emle49).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you don't use php.ini inside xampp but C:\Program Files (x86)\php\php.ini
Your php.ini try to search settings in C:\Program Files (x86)\php\php.ini
do you have another istance of php installed on your pc?
maybe in PATH environment php.exe path is out of folder of xampp
you can try to remove semicolon from C:\Program Files (x86)\php\php.ini to pdo_mysql and should fix your problem
but better solution is to fix PATH environment in windows to search php.exe in c:\xampp\php